On Windows 11, Run Linux (via docker) with jq then throwaway
I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69658565/unable-to-download-the-jq-package :
Made a docker file:
FROM alpine
RUN apk update && apk add wget

RUN wget https://github.com/jqlang/jq/releases/download/jq-1.7.1/jq-linux-amd64 && \
    mv jq-linux64 /usr/local/bin/jq && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/jq

Ran it in cmd.exe as
docker build -t linux1-image -f Dockerfile1.txt 

from same directory as the file is saved, But it fails on the 2nd line. Get output:
> 2024/07/10 03:00:30 http2: server: error reading preface from client

> //./pipe/docker_engine: file has already been close[+] Building 0.6s
> 
> (5/6)                                                                  
> docker:default  => [internal] load build definition from
> Dockerfile1.txt                                                       
> 0.0s  => => transferring dockerfile: 370B                                                                               > 0.0s  => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                   > 0.0s  => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  > 0.0s  => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    > 0.0s  => CACHED [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                              > 0.0s  => ERROR [2/3] RUN apk update &&     apk add wget                                                                 > 0.5s
> ------
>  > [2/3] RUN apk update &&     apk add wget:
> 0.226 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
> 0.380 288BA427E57F0000:error:0A000086:SSL routines:tls_post_process_server_certificate:certificate verify
> failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:2091:
> 0.381 WARNING: updating and opening https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/main: Permission denied
> 0.381 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
> 0.481 288BA427E57F0000:error:0A000086:SSL routines:tls_post_process_server_certificate:certificate verify
> failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:2091:
> 0.482 4 unavailable, 0 stale; 14 distinct packages available
> 0.482 WARNING: updating and opening https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/community: Permission
> denied
> ------

my goal is to run a linux box where I can run commands like jq and sed for a few hours and then close it down, from my local windows 11 OS. I have admin priviledges. I run other dockers with java processes.
I have WSL 2 installed and docker on top of that, done in May, so pretty recent versions

You should use WSL and Docker to accomplish your task.

my docker is running on WSL @ramhound but this dockerfile is not running, wanted help to fix it
